# Moq Timeout Exception C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, moq

I am using the Moq testing framework in C#, and I trying to create a unit test where I have a method which calls out to a service on a remote server over a unreliable network.

In side the method I am trying to unit test I have the following code:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.remoteClient.SomeMethod(userDetails)).Wait(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));
```

The aim of the unit test is to mock out the timeout where the service failed to respond within 10 seconds.

So far I have the unit test as follows, which does work, but I am feeling that it is not quite right.

```
   mockRemoteClientService.Setup(r =>r.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(11000));
```

Can anyone advise me whether the approach I am taking is correct or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Quick observation. Are you mixing async and blocking calls? Also it is advised to avoid using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and instead use `Task.Run`. Maybe then you could use a cancellation token with a given time span to complete.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Comment: Did you see that I put c# Framework 4.0? Task.Run does not exist in Framework 4.0# and I cannot up the version. Therefore, I have to use the Factory.StartNew method

Comment: I stand corrected. Did not notice that tag.

Comment: Check the overloads for StartNew and see if any take a cancellation token.

Comment: Cool. The reason why I am using the Task.Factory approach, is that I do not want the call to the remote service to be in a single thread and block our application. So, when the call to remote service is called and nothing happens after 10 seconds, I just want it to timeout . The remote service is a bit rubbish and on a shocking network. Therefore, if nothing happens, I just want our code not to be blocked and just carries on

Comment: I do hope then that you have that 3rd party dependency abstracted away.

Comment: Can you still provide more context around the subject code being called. could help with devising a viable workaround.

Comment: It is a service that uses the Thrift Protocol over a mobile phone network

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cancellation token to setup the actual timeout.

When you want to mock out the service call to simulate a timeout, you can use `Throws` (or `ThrowsAsync` in case of an async method) to throw a `TaskCancelledException` or `TimeOutException` like so:

```
mockRemoteClientService.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>())).Throw(new TaskCancelledException());
```

Then `Assert` that you handle the response correctly.